# Is development with Adobe CQ5 (AEM) programming at all?

Tags: java, content-management-system, aem

I'm really confused, what kind of job it would be working with Adobe CQ5 (Adobe Experience Manager)? Is it programming or is it just working with some GUI, tools, etc, since it's a CMS after all?

I have the chance to participate this CQ5 advanced developer training and later going to a job related to it:
http://training.adobe.com/training/courses/cq5-advanced-developer.html

I basically want to be a Java developer/programmer, I'm confused. Is this for me? Or is it just some tool and not much programming at all? So what kind of work is it?

Please help me, I'm very confused, I have to decide quite quickly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about career advice

Comment: @dystroy it is somewhat. But I really need to know what is working with CQ5. Is it programming, or is it just working with some cms tool like Joomla in PHP? If you have a better tip where I could get more and better answers then tell me...

Comment: @dystroy is right. This is off topic. Go to vendor page and look for. This just looks like an advertisement and should be removed.

Comment: This question is interesting for me.

Comment: @Roland Trust me, I did go to Vendor page and I did review the training plan for it. I don't see anything advertisement related here. It can be really hard if you need to quickly understand what it's like to work with some platform/system. Sure the question is not about a bug or something, but people more often use Stackoverflow, because it has many qualified users, which in this case can give decent answers/advice.

Answer (score 7):

CQ5 is a platform based on [Apache Felix](https://felix.apache.org), [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org/), [JCR](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/) and other technologies. It comes with a basic set of components, workflows and other features but creating an actual custom site always requires creating OSGi services, servlets, models, etc. In fact, [all topics](http://training.adobe.com/training/courses/cq5-advanced-developer/_jcr_content/courseInformationOnline) in the course you've referred to are strictly programming subjects. CQ5 technology stack is quite exotic, but I think it only makes it more interesting.

Answering your question: yes, it is programming.

Comment: Your answer might have seemed inconsequential to you when you wrote it but it was actually germane to me.   I was looking through job offers and ran across the phrase "proficient in AEM and Java" and had no idea what AEM was until then.